# Upgrading from Spring 2.5.x to Spring 4.x

Tags: spring-mvc

I need to upgrade a medium sized web application from **`Spring 2.5 to Spring 4.x.`** 
I replaced **`Spring 2.5 jars`** with **`4.3.2 jars`** and I found around 100 errors like `SimpleFormController name not resolved, queryforInt() not recognized` etc. Should I use `@Controller` for controllers and use **`auto-wire`** the dependencies ?. That means I should convert all classes to annotation based using `@component, @Resource, @Controller` etc  ? What is the best approach...Please suggest

Comment: Yes use annotations, its the better way to do..and in future also it will be easy to modify(Code maintenance too).

Answer (score 0):

You need to move from using [`SimpleFormController`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/mvc/SimpleFormController.html), it has been deprecated from spring 3.x and removed in 4.x. Start writing your controllers with `@Controller` annotation.

Should you use `@Component`, `@Service`, and autowire? It's probably best you do that, but not necessarily. You can still use your factory classes to create objects if you want. But using spring `@Autowired` dependency would make your life easier.